# Understanding backpressure in akka streams Source.queue

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream

I'm trying out akka streams, but i can't get backpressure to work in my simple example. I am admittely not experienced with akka (streams), so probably I'm missing something big.

I am producing (offering on a queue) integers faster than consuming them, so I thought that backpressure would kick in.
My goal is to always consume the most recent item that was put in the queue (that's why I have bufferSize = 1 and 
OverflowStrategy.dropHead() on the source queue).

```
public class SimpleStream {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws InterruptedException {
        final ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("akka-streams");
        final Materializer materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system);

        final Procedure<Integer> slowConsumer = (i) -> {
            System.out.println("consuming [" + i + "]");
            ThreadUtils.sleepQuietly(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        };

        final SourceQueue<Integer> q = Sink
                .<Integer>foreach(slowConsumer)
                .runWith(Source.<Integer>queue(1, OverflowStrategy.dropHead()),  materializer);

        final AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
        final Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                int n = i.incrementAndGet(); 
                q.offer(n);
                System.out.println("produced: [" + n + "]");
                ThreadUtils.sleepQuietly(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            }
        });
        t.setName("ticking");
        t.start();

        // run some time... to observe the effects.
        ThreadUtils.sleepQuietly(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        t.interrupt();
        t.join();

        // eventually shutdown akka here...
    }
}
```

However this is the result:

```
produced: [1]
consuming [1]
produced: [2]
produced: [3]
consuming [2] <-- Expected to be consuming 3 here.
produced: [4]
produced: [5]
consuming [3] <-- Expected to be consuming 5 here.
produced: [6]
produced: [7]
```

Please ignore the threading stuff here and there just to fake getting data from an external
source (like it would happen if I had to use this in a real project).

Any idea of what I'm missing?

Comment: Backpressure won't work with `Source.queue`. You can call its `offer` as many times as possible. You need to check what `offer` returns. You most likely want producer to be independent from consumer queue. Take a look at `MergeHub`. Perhaps it will work better for you.

Answer (score 2):

`Source.queue` terminates the signalling of back pressure.  That is why the Source.queue method takes in an `OverflowStrategy`.  If back pressure could be signalled upstream past the queue then there would be no need to deal with a situation where the queue could potentially overflow.  But since back pressure does not propagate past the queue a strategy needs to be defined to deal with a producer that is faster than a consumer.

With typical streams the ultimate `Source` receives demand from the `Sink` to produce more results.  However, with a stream created from `Source.queue` the "ultimate source" is a queue.  This queue can only drain the contents, if there is any.  It can't signal upstream to generate more results because the upstream is on the other side of the `offer` method.

Comment: Ok, makes sense that "backpressure" can't be propagated upward past the queue. In my question i'm calling "backpressure" the enforcement of the overflow strategy by the queue. It would be fine if that overflow strategy was working despite of the name (i.e. it's backpressure or not).